# Getting 403 forbidden error when trying authenticate application server with C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I created a simple web application and hosted it on local server (local host) and used the below code to get the authentication id, but it return 403 error. also is there any way to send message to C2DM without application server I mean from desktop application?

here is my code to get authentication key:

```
 string GetToken()
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {


        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("Email=").Append("MyGmailEmailAddress");
        builder.Append("&Passwd=").Append("MyPassword");
        builder.Append("&accountType=GOOGLE");
        builder.Append("&source=PingMe");
        builder.Append("&service=ac2dm");

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
        stream.Close();

        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader  = new StreamReader(stream);

        return  reader.ReadToEnd();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(response != null)
                response.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the Web Server are you using on local ? wampServer , EasyPHP or what ??

Comment: IIS, and created web application in .net

Comment: in Wamp Server , there is an option called : pass to OnLine Mode , i don't know if it is in your Web Server , try to put it in OnLine Mode , and re try

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same...

Answer (score 0):

People are strongly recommending a dedicated Google account for C2DM. Don't use your regular GMail.

Also, have you signed up at http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html ? If yes, *try signing up again*, with the same Google account. That site is notoriously wonky.